# How to get labels of nodes of neo4j network in cytoscape

Tags: neo4j, cytoscape

I am using cytoscape pluggin (cypher queries) to visualize neo4j graph db. I am using following query to visualize it. The output shows the 37 nodes and connections but the nodes and connections do not have any labels.

I am using following cypher query:

```
match (g: Gene) where g.symbol = 'TMPRSS2' or g.symbol='ACE2'
with g
match path=(g)<-[:IS_VARIANT_OF_GENE|DISEASE_ASSOCIATES_GENE]-()
return path
```

How can I visualize the network with all the labels.

Any help is here highly appreciated

Comment: Is this a plugin for native cytoscape or for visualizing in cytoscapeJS?
I'm having a similar problem but trying to visualize with the JS version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the labels from everything in that path, you could so something like:

```
MATCH (g:Gene) where g.symbol = 'TMPRSS2' or g.symbol='ACE2'
WITH g
MATCH (g)<-[r:IS_VARIANT_OF_GENE|DISEASE_ASSOCIATES_GENE]-(n)
return g, r, n
```

That should return you the nodes, relationship, and their properties. I'm not familiar with Cytoscape but without knowing anything about it, that's how I would get the properties back.